# Is there a way to style an element according to it's existing attributes on CSS?

Tags: css

I want to simplify my code and I was wondering if there is a way to tell CSS to effect it's children elements according to what the parents attributes are.

(Maybe this statement is too broad, below you can see more specifically what I'm trying to accomplish)

```
#blueBtn {
    background-color: #00f;
    color: white;
    border-color: #00f;
}

#blueBtn:disabled {
    background-color: #33f;
    color: gray;
    border-color: #33f;
}

#greenBtn {
    background-color: #0f0;
    color: white;
    border-color: #0f0;
}

#greenBtn:disabled {
    background-color: #393;
    color: #aaa;
    border-color: #393;
}
```

I want a way to **add** `3` to each number that is `0` when the button is enabled. For example, if I had a `redBtn` it's colors would be `#f00` and when disabled `#f33`.

That way I would only need one selector (`button.disabled`) to affect any color button.

Comment: I don't believe you can do it in raw CSS. You can get close to it by using a CSS preprocessor such as [Sass][1], or [Stylus][2], they provide functions such as `lighten` or `darken` which takes a color and manipulates it by a certain %. But if you want specific control like only turning 0s into 3s in a color, then I think you're only option left is JavaScript.

[1]: https://sass-lang.com
[2]: http://stylus-lang.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> effect it's children elements according to what the parents attributes are

That's just how CSS works (*Cascading* Style Sheets). But what you are trying to do is get the actual value. So no, not directly in the way you are thinking (as in have access to the computed value). There are a few ways around this but one solution is to take advantage of a variable. This wouldn't work with all property value pairs, but I think this scenario is a good fit.  All I did was turn down the lightness for their `hsl` value:

```css
.redBtn {
    --color: 0;
    background-color: hsl(var(--color), 100%, 50%);
}

.blueBtn {
    --color: 255;
    background-color: hsl(var(--color), 100%, 50%);
}

.greenBtn {
    --color: 100;
    background-color: hsl(var(--color), 100%, 50%);
}


[disabled] {
    background-color: hsl(var(--color),100%, 30%);
    color: #aaa;
}





button { width: 150px; height: 75px; color: white; }
button:active { border: 3px solid cornflowerblue; }
```

```html
<button class="redBtn" disabled>Disabled Red Button</button>
<button class="blueBtn" >Blue Button</button>
<button class="greenBtn" >Green Button</button>
<button class="greenBtn" disabled>Disabled Grn Button</button>
<button class="redBtn" >Red Button</button>
<button class="blueBtn" disabled>Disabled Blue Button</button>
<button class="redBtn" disabled>Disabled Red Button</button>
<button class="blueBtn" disabled>Disabled Blue Button</button>
<button class="redBtn" >Red Button</button>
<button class="greenBtn" disabled>Disabled Grn Button</button>
<button class="greenBtn" >Green Button</button>
<button class="blueBtn" >Blue Button</button>
```

Edit: Not sure how cross-browser compatible this is, as always, check IE :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, not only did this solve my problem, it also gave me a whole new perspective on to how to use CSS.